# Can I run a C# application developed on a 64-bit system on a 32-bit system?

Tags: c#, .net

Fellow programmers, if i made a C# app on 64-bit system will i be able to run it without problems on 32-bit system (or 32-bit on 64-bit) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably build the application executable with the CPU type set to 32-bit, and any class libraries set to "Any CPU". Unless you really *need* the CLR to force 64-bit mode, [32-bit can be more efficient](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/8/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx). (This is the default in VS2010, IIRC.)

If you're referencing any native libraries, it can get a little hairier, IIRC - you need to make sure you're using the right version of the library on each architecture. I'm not terribly experienced in that side of things, to be honest. [This blog post](http://sander.rijken.info/post/2962785666/net-interop-targeting-x86-vs-x64-vs-anycpu) may help you though.

Comment: That's correct. The `BadImageFormatException` is thrown if one try to load an assembly that got the wrong bitness. As for COM, your application will simply not find the correct component.

Comment: Why executable needs to be build with CPU type set to 32 bit?

Answer (score 3):

You should compile it for Any Cpu configuration. With this configuration it works both in 32/64 bit without problem ( if you have com interop or PInvoke inside your code is a longer story )